# Why are Jest test naming conventions the way they are?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Why are Jest test naming conventions the way they are?

- Why are test folders named `__tests__`, with the underscores?
- Why are test files suffixed with `-test.js` as opposed to just `something.js`?

Answer (score 13):

Underscores and double underscores are commonly used to denote things which are outside of the regular code. For example, Python uses them to prefix object properties which are private or system-controlled.

In this sense, your tests folder isn't part of your app, it's something which sits alongside it. To stretch a hypothetical example, imagine you were writing an app to control science experiments. You might want a folder called, legitimately, `tests`. That would be arguably insane, the point is that `__tests__` makes it clear that the tests are not part of the main line of code.

The `-test` suffix is just for test discovery. Lots of frameworks use similar prefix or suffix conventions.